# Getting error Required request part 'logoURL' is not present

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, jsp, multipartform-data

I am trying to save a simple form with an image logo but I am getting **HTTP 400** in browser console. and **Required request part 'logoURL' is not present** Please see my code and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Master Ajax:** The class I have made for sending request and response from Ajax

```
class MasterAjax{
    constructor(){
        this.requestType = null;
        this.url = null;
        this.timeout = 100000;
        this.enctype =  null;
        this.data = null;
        this.processData = null;
        this.contentType = null;
        this.responseData = null;
        this.responseStatus = null;
        this.responseStatusCode = null;
    }
    
    requestData(callBack){
        
        var parameterError=false;
        if(null == this.requestType){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: Request Type can't be null");
        }    
        if(null === this.url || undefined === this.url || "undefined" === this.url){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: URL can't be null");
        }  
        if(null == this.data || this.data.length <= 0){
            //console.log("Warning: Data is null");
        }
        if(parameterError === false){
            /*toggleSpinnerOn();  */
            $.ajax({
                type : this.requestType,
                enctype : this.enctype,
                processData : this.processData, 
                contentType : this.contentType, 
//              url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
            url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
                data: this.data,
                timeout : this.timeout,
                success : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus);
                },
                error : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus); 
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Store Form**

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/Store/StoreTemplet/Header.jsp"%>
<%-- <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/testEstimation/TestEstimationPhases.js"/>"></script> --%>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="<c:url value="/js/storejs/storejs.js"/>"></script>
<!-- Content wrapper start -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <h2 class="card-title">New Store</h2>
        <form name="storeForms"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Hidden For Update employee  -->
            <input type="hidden" />
            <!-- First row -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Store Name</label>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                        id="storeName" placeholder="Store Name" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" id="country"  class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Second row container -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Street</label>
                    <input type="text" id="street" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Third row container -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" id="zipCode" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Store Description</label>
                    <input type="text" id="storeDescription"
                        class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Store Timings</label>
                    <input type="text" id="storeOpenTime" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" id="file-input-2"  data-default-value="Store Logo" />
  <label for="file-input-2">Store logo</label>
</div>
            <!-- Submit button container -->
            <div class="text-right">
                <!-- text-right = text-align: right -->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="saveStore()" value="Add Store">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Content wrapper end -->

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/Store/StoreTemplet/Footer.jsp"%>
```

**Ajax Request Method**

```
function saveStore(){
 
let formData = new FormData();

//formData.append("key" , Value ) ; 
    formData.append("storeName", $("#storeName").val());
    formData.append("country", $("#country").val());
    formData.append("city", $("#city").val());
    formData.append("street", $("#street").val());
    formData.append("address", $("#address").val());
    formData.append("zipCode", $("#zipCode").val());
    formData.append("storeDescription", $("#storeDescription").val());
    formData.append("storeOpenTime", $("#storeOpenTime").val());
    formData.append('logoFile', $("#logoURL").val());

    var obj = new MasterAjax();
    obj.requestType = "POST";
    obj.url = "store/saveStore";
    obj.data = formData;
    obj.enctype ="multipart/form-data";   
    obj.contentType = false;
    obj.processData = false;
    obj.dataType= "json";
    console.log("---------------------------")

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ': ' + pair[1]); 
    }
    console.log("---------------------------")

    obj.requestData(function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData);
        if(responseData.status == "OK" || responseData.status == "ok"){
            alert("success");
            console.log(responseData)
        }else{
            alert(" failed");
            console.log(responseData)
        }
    }); 
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class StoreController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStore" , method = {RequestMethod.POST},consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public APIResponseModal saveStore(@ModelAttribute("storeForm") StoresDTO store, 
            BindingResult bres,
            @RequestParam("logoURL") MultipartFile file) {
        
        logger.info("Store Save MEthod callled !!!!!!!!");
        Stores storeModal  = new Stores();
        String logopath = "";
        APIResponseModal apiResponse = new Utils().getDefaultApiResponse();
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            if(store !=null){
                storeModal = new Stores(store);
                if(!file.isEmpty()) {
                    if(file.getSize()>1000000) {//1000000 bytes == 1 mb
                        errorList.add("File size should be less than 1 MB");
                        //                    return AJax
                    }
                    logopath = Utils.storeLogoPath(file);
                }
                storeService.saveStore(storeModal, errorList,logopath);
                
                if(errorList.isEmpty() && !Utils.isNotNull(errorList)) {
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                    apiResponse.setData("--");
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Store Saved Successfully !!");
                }else {
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Failed to save store !!");
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            apiResponse.setData("--");
            apiResponse.setMessage("Error Occured at our end !!");          
        }
        logger.info("API RESPONSE:: ::"+ apiResponse);
        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

**SaveStore Method**

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveStore(Stores store,List<String> errorList,String logoPath) {

        try {
            if(Utils.isNotNull(store)) {
                if(Utils.isNotNull(store.getStoreName())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getAddress())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getCountry())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getCity())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getStreet())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getStoreOpenTime())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getZipCode())
                        &Utils.isNotNull(store.getStoreDescription())
                        ) {
                    store.setAddedAt(new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    store.setStoreOwner(1);
                    store.setUniqueStoreCode(store.getStoreName().substring(0,2)+Utils.RandomAlphaString());
                    store.setStoreStatus(Constants.storeStatus.OPEN);
                    store.setLogoURL(logoPath);
                    entityManager.merge(store);
                }else {
                    errorList.add("Please Enter required Details !");
                }
            }else {
                errorList.add("Please Enter required Details !");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Exception Occured in Save Store Method : " + e.getMessage());
            errorList.add("Error Occured at our End we are Sorry !! Please try again later");
        }
    }
```

**IDE Console**

```
 Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'logoURL' is not present]
```

**Browser Console**

```
Status400
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred1.26 KB (1.10 KB size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Comment: What is inside your `saveStore` function ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy Save store function is just saving all the data in Database I have added the save store method just below controller

Comment: I have posted an answer, does that help ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy  No Still getting the same Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were  multiple issues in the code here firstly I removed the  `@RequestParam("logoURL") MultipartFile file` parameter from controller as I was sending the file in my DTO so there is not need for that here.(This will be working fine if you are sending the data using spring form and no AJAX) so the controller will now look like

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStore" , method = {RequestMethod.POST})
        public APIResponseModal saveStore(@ModelAttribute StoresDTO store,HttpSession session)
```

Other issue was on Ajax Request file where I am sending the data to controller on Line 14 the code is `formData.append('logoFile', $("#logoURL").val());` which is not correct here I am just sending the file name not the file that is the reason I was getting type mismatched exception As my DTO variable is of type Multipart and I was trying to send the String here so the Code I replaced here is `formData.append('logoFile', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the `name` parameter that needs to be added to the form fields

So you input fields should be

`<input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control" />`

Add the same to your `file` field.

And also what is your `saveStore` function doing ?